# Send multiple parameters to flask-restplus

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restplus

When creating an API that takes one argument from the request, I use this code:

```
class test(Resource):
    def get(self,id):
        return id

api.add_resource(test, '/endpoint/<int:id>')
```

What would I do if I need it to take multiple parameters?

I'm using python 3 and flask-restplus.

Any help is very appreciated!

BR Kresten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Flask-RESTPlus* provides documentation for things that are unique to it. Everything other is documented in *Flask*, since Flask-RESTPlus is built on top of Flask.

In Flask (*and Flask-RESTPlus of course* ), you can use [Variable Rules](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules). And you can use it as many as you like:

```
class Test(Resource):
    def get(self, name, surname, age):
        return name + surname + str(age)

api.add_resource(Test, '/endpoint/<string:name>/<string:surname>/<int:age>')
```

But, consider using query arguments with `RequestParser`<sup>[1](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parsing.html)</sup>
.